# How can i hide parts of the UI?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using vscode in to teach programming with git.
I would like to hide some of the menu items in the source control tab, so it only shows the basic git commands like push and pull instead of all of them, is this possible?

[image: Source control menu]

Comment: You would have to modify the code in VS Code... Since those are integrated.

Comment: much better to learn git from the command line